# How to fix UserPrincipalNotFoundException when calling an API in pyspark application?

Tags: python, rest, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to submit API calls from a Spark application as below:

```
def api_json(spark, api_param):
    try:
      token = generate_a_token()
      token_headers = {'Authorization': f"Bearer {token}"}
      response = requests.get(f'https://api_url/?api_end_point={api_param}', headers=token_headers)
      json_data = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([response.text])
      df = spark.read.json(json_data)
      df.show()
      return df
    except Exception as error:
      traceback.print_exc()


def generate_a_token():
  token_data = {
    some_key1: some_value1,
    some_key2: some_value2
  }
  headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
  data = bytes(urlencode(token_data).encode())
  req = request.Request(url, data, headers)
  try:
    response = request.urlopen(req)
    json_response = json.load(response)
    token = json_response["access_token"]
    print(token)
  except Exception as e:
    print('Some Exception')
  return token
```

When I run this application, I see an exception:

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o305.getTrustedPath.
> : java.nio.file.attribute.UserPrincipalNotFoundException

I haven't faced an exception like this until and now and have no idea what it is. Full exception stack is given below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/local_disk0/tmp/spark-some-path/pyspark_template-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl/src/tests/Api_Response.py", line 23, in api_json
    json_data = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([response.text])
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 562, in parallelize
    jrdd = session._create_rdd_from_local_trusted(c, numSlices, serializer)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 516, in _create_rdd_from_local_trusted
    temp_data_path = self._write_to_trusted_path(data, serializer)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 485, in _write_to_trusted_path
    temp_dir = self._jsparkSession.getTrustedPath()
  File "/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1305, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 127, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o305.getTrustedPath.
: java.nio.file.attribute.UserPrincipalNotFoundException
  at sun.nio.fs.UnixUserPrincipals.lookupName(UnixUserPrincipals.java:155)
  at sun.nio.fs.UnixUserPrincipals.lookupUser(UnixUserPrincipals.java:170)
  at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystem$LookupService$1.lookupPrincipalByName(UnixFileSystem.java:330)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.TrustedPathHelper.createTrustedTempDir(TrustedPathHelper.scala:86)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.TrustedPathHelper.createTrustedTempDir$(TrustedPathHelper.scala:81)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.createTrustedTempDir(SparkSession.scala:87)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.TrustedPathHelper.getTrustedPath(TrustedPathHelper.scala:129)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.TrustedPathHelper.getTrustedPath$(TrustedPathHelper.scala:128)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.getTrustedPath(SparkSession.scala:87)
  at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
  at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

As you can see, the exception exactly occurs at the line:

```
json_data = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([response.text])
```

I printed the API call result using a print statement and was able to see the JSON(which is the payload returned from API call).
I am converting this code into a whl file, create a cluster and then submit it on databricks.
For pyspark run time libraries I am using a docker image.
Is there anything wrong in the way I configured the API calls in Spark?
Could anyone let me know what is the mistake I am doing here and how can I correct it?
Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: `_jsparkSession` is a `org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession` object. And it's invoking the method `getTrustedPath`. But I can not find that method anywhere. I've checked the [API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.1/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.html), but it's not there. I created a `SparkSession` in `pyspark` and tried to invoke it manually, but it says that the method `getTrustedPath` does not exists. Where does that method comes from?

Comment: [Searching directly on github repo code](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Aapache%2Fspark%20getTrust&type=code) I can not see it neither.

Comment: Can you share your docker image as well?

Answer (score 0):

Reading [Interface UserPrincipal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/UserPrincipal.html), a "Principal" represents an identity used to determine access rights to objects in a file system.

> On many platforms and file systems an entity requires appropriate access rights or permissions in order to access objects in a file system. The access rights are generally performed by checking the identity of the entity. For example, on implementations that use Access Control Lists (ACLs) to enforce privilege separation then a file in the file system may have an associated ACL that determines the access rights of identities specified in the ACL.

Running your PySpark application inside a Docker container means possible issues related to filesystem permissions and user principals. When a Docker container runs with a mounted volume, the user inside the container needs to have appropriate permissions to access that volume. If these permissions are not set up correctly, it could lead to a `UserPrincipalNotFoundException`.

For instance, the user ID and group ID inside the container might not map correctly to those of the mounted volume on the host machine. This could prevent access to specific directories or files, triggering the exception.

So check the user running inside the Docker container has permissions to access the mounted volume. This may require adjusting the user ID and group ID to match those of the host machine.

And check the requirement, should you have [customize containers with Databricks Container Services](https://docs.databricks.com/en/clusters/custom-containers.html).

Answer (score 0):

The error message, java.nio.file.attribute.UserPrincipalNotFoundException, suggests that there is an issue with file permissions or user privileges when Spark is trying to create a temporary directory for parallelizing data. It doesn't seem to be directly related to your API call configuration.

To address this issue, you can try the following steps:

Check File Permissions:
Ensure that the user running the Spark application has the necessary permissions to create temporary directories and files in the Spark working directory. You might need to check the permissions on the directory where Spark is trying to create temporary files.

Set a Temporary Directory:
You can explicitly set a temporary directory for Spark to use by configuring the spark.local.dir property in your Spark application. For example:

```
 spark = SparkSession.builder \
 .appName("YourAppName") \
 .config("spark.local.dir", "/your/preferred/temporary/directory") \
 .getOrCreate()
```

Replace "/your/preferred/temporary/directory" with a directory where the Spark user has write permissions.

Specify a Different Storage Level:
If specifying a temporary directory doesn't resolve the issue, you can try using a different storage level for the json_data RDD. Instead of parallelize, you can use textFile to read the JSON data from a file as follows:

```
 json_data = spark.read.textFile("file:///path/to/temporary/file")
 df = spark.read.json(json_data)
 df.show()
```

This approach reads data from a file, which might help bypass the temporary directory issue.

Debugging:
If the issue persists, it's worth investigating the specific directory where Spark is trying to create temporary files and checking if there are any unusual permissions or limitations imposed by the environment you are running Spark in. Additionally, make sure you are using a compatible version of Spark for your environment.

By following these steps and ensuring that Spark has the necessary permissions and configurations, you should be able to resolve the UserPrincipalNotFoundException error.